# DAX - Multiple tables & columns with measures in Power BI Import

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas

I am writing a DAX query to be used while performing a Power BI SQL Server Analysis Services database Import. I want to limit the fields and records to be used. I cannot figure out how to include measures in my query. Any help would be appreciated!

This works:

```
EVALUATE (
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
'Date PT'[Calendar Date PT],
'Date PT'[Fiscal Month PT],
'Date PT'[Fiscal Year PT],
'Issue Code'[Code 2],
'Planning Cat'[Planning Area],
FILTER('Date PT', 'Date PT'[Fiscal Year PT]= "FY22"),
FILTER('Planning Cat', [Planning Area]= "NOA")
)
)
```

I need to add in **Sales by Booked Date (a measure)** and I get an error stating that this field "cannot be found or cannot be used in this expression"

**THIS DOES NOT WORK**

```
EVALUATE ( 
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
'Date PT'[Calendar Date PT],
'Date PT'[Fiscal Month PT],
'Date PT'[Fiscal Year PT],
'Issue Code'[Code 2], 
'Planning Cat'[Planning Area],
'Sales'[Sales by Booked Date],
FILTER('Date PT', 'Date PT'[Fiscal Year PT]= "FY22"), 
FILTER('Planning Cat', [Planning Area]= "NOA") 
) 
)
```

I have tried everything I can find but nothing seems to work. If I leave a measure out, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
EVALUATE  
ADDCOLUMNS(
   SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
      'Date PT'[Calendar Date PT], 
      'Date PT'[Fiscal Month PT], 
      'Date PT'[Fiscal Year PT], 
      'Issue Code'[Code 2], 
      'Planning Cat'[Planning Area], 
      FILTER(
         'Date PT', 
         'Date PT'[Fiscal Year PT]= "FY22"
      ), 
      FILTER(
         'Planning Cat', 
         [Planning Area]= "NOA"
      ) 
   ),
   "@SalesByBookedDate", CALCULATE ( 'Sales'[Sales by Booked Date] )
)
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much as I have spent hours trying to figure this out! Out of curiosity, why does the measure need to be contained outside of the main query--is it because you cannot use SUMMARIZECOLUMNS on a measure?

Comment: Actually, you've put the measure there like the standard column, so the engine doesn't know what is that.  You could do that inside `SUMMARIZECOLUMN` but first you have to specify the column name, e.g. `"TotalQuantity", [YourMeasure]`. There are also several things related to the row context that you always should take into account.
In this case, it is almost always the best practice to not compute the measures inside `SUMMARIZE` or `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS` due to performance issues. Use `SUMMARIZE` to group and `ADDCOLUMNS` to add additional columns to the grouped table.